# How do i display data from multiple lists?

Tags: list

I want to have a web part which displays a list of items.  This would not be a sharepoint list but a list from multiple datasources e.g. output has a total of 8 columns

2 columns are from a sharepoint list (Users)
2 columns are from a custom sharepoint list
3 columns are accessed from a web service to a external system (e.g. share price from yahoo)
1 columns is calculated (complex calculation) using the other 5 columns

How would i do this? What controls/objects would i need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the Content Query Web part.

[Take a look at this designer link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-designer-help/display-data-from-multiple-lists-with-the-content-query-web-part-HA010174134.aspx)

Comment: would this work with web service calls?

Comment: No. If you want to use web services then you will need a custom webpart/control to deal with the data.

Comment: Im thinking about creating a data table and populating it and binding this to SPGridView. Can you think of any better ways?

Comment: If that is how you want the data to display, then it is a good way.