# How to access list data using a web part?

Tags: web-part, list

I have a list which displays multiple rows of text. Is there a custom Sharepoint web part I can use to select specific row ?

This question [How do i display data from multiple lists?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51169/how-do-i-display-data-from-multiple-lists) is in relation to multiple lists, is the process the same for a single list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the link you provided, you can choose to use the Content Query Web Part.

You can choose your list as the source, and then make a query to display the specific rows you want to show.

The default presentation template for Content Query Web Part might not display the list as you want (for example, not enough columns).

But you can add more slots in or change the presentation in ItemStyle.xsl and ContentQueryMain.xsl in your Style Library Directory.

Link about CQWP: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650512.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes that would work for a singular list or you could use just a plain list view web part for your list with a view configured as desired and used in the web part.